# PHP syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php

edit: this is due to content not requiring parsing as php.

I have a very basic webpage that doesn't seem to like my google tracking code. My web server renders

`PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<'"`

referring to the first `<script>` line. I am really unable to see how it thinks there is an extra "<" in there. If I replace the script content with `echo "blah";`, the page renders fine.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-gwryhaehsd', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question shows an epic amount of lack of effort.

Comment: `<script>` is infact HTML. It's ok, I'm not angry. You just show complete ignorance of the technology you are dealing with, so my advice would be to learn what you're doing first. Then no one will have to waste time.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you've surrounded your Google Analytics tracking script with `<?php ?>` tags.  Remove them and it'll work.

Comment: I've done this because I am rendering php within a HTML page. As such, I need to include this to have the script parsed as php. Is this not possible?

Comment: @Peter you do not need the js script to be parsed as php.

Comment: You only need to surround your PHP code with `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: @Peter - There is absolutely no php to render on that page you've shown in your question, just HTML markup and javascript

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `<?php` and `?>` before and after your `<script>` tag.